# Variadic Functions in Scheme (using nested maps)

Tags: maps, scheme

I have to define a variadic function in Scheme that takes the following form: `(define (n-loop procedure [a list of pairs (x,y)])` where the list of pairs can be any length.

Each pair specifies a lower (inclusive) and upper bound (exclusive). That is, the following function call: `(n-loop (lambda (x y) (inspect (list x y))) (0 2) (0 3))` produces:

```
(list x y) is (0 0)
(list x y) is (0 1)
(list x y) is (0 2)
(list x y) is (1 0)
(list x y) is (1 1)
(list x y) is (1 2)
```

Now, I had posted on this topic one previous time and was helped wonderfully. However, I have been given new guidelines to adhere to. The solution is to be found using nested maps only.

The way I've been going about this is as follows: find all of the values specified by the first set of bounds (in the example, `(0 1 2)`). This can be done by a function called `(enumerate lowBound highBound)`. Then, I need to take each of those numbers, and cons each number in the next set of bounds `(0 1 2 3)`, resulting in `((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (1 0)...)`.

What I've written to this point is the following:

```
(define (n-loop op . pairs)
     (apply op (generate pairs))
)

(define (generate pairs)
    (map (lambda (x) (cons x (generate (cdr pairs)))) 
         (map (lambda (x) (enumerate (car x) (cadr x))) pairs))
)
```

But for the given numbers, this outputs `(0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2)` when I need `((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (1 0)...)`. This is a nasty problem. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is more complex than you seem to realize. In particular, generating the cartesian product of an arbitrary list of ranges needs far more work - have you tried your procedure with more than two ranges? It piqued my interest, this time I'll give my shot to a complete solution, using only procedures defined for the solution, simple operations over lists (`cons`, `car`, `cdr`, `append`), `lambda`, `apply` and `map`.

First, the helper procedures from simplest to hardest. We need a way to generate a range of numbers. If available, use `build-list` or `for-list`, but if you need to implement it from scratch:

```
(define (enumerate low high)
  (if (>= low high)
      '()
      (cons low
            (enumerate (add1 low) high))))
```

Now we need a mechanism for folding (reducing, accumulating) the values in a list. If available use `foldr`, otherwise implement it like this:

```
(define (reduce proc lst init)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (proc (car lst)
            (reduce proc (cdr lst) init))))
```

To avoid unnecessary nesting in lists, use a `flatmap` - a procedure that both maps and flattens a list of values:

```
(define (flatmap proc lst)
  (reduce (lambda (e acc)
            (append (proc e) acc))
          lst '()))
```

This is the core of the solution - a procedure that generates the cartesian product of an arbitrarily long list of lists of values denoting ranges:

```
(define (product . args)
  (reduce (lambda (pool result)
            (flatmap (lambda (x)
                       (map (lambda (y)
                              (cons x y))
                            result))
                     pool))
          args
          '(())))
```

Finally, the procedure in the question. It uses the helper procedures defined above, noticing that the `op` received can have an arbitrary number of parameters (depending on the number of ranges specified), so we need to use `apply` on each generated tuple of values:

```
(define (n-loop op . pairs)
  (map (lambda (tuple) (apply op tuple))
       (apply product
              (map (lambda (pair)
                     (enumerate (car pair) (cadr pair)))
                   pairs))))
```

Test it like this:

```
(n-loop (lambda (x y z) (list x y z))
        '(0 2) '(0 3) '(4 6))

> '((0 0 4) (0 0 5) (0 1 4) (0 1 5) (0 2 4) (0 2 5)
    (1 0 4) (1 0 5) (1 1 4) (1 1 5) (1 2 4) (1 2 5))
```

Comment: Right. I already had enumerate, accumulate, and flatmap defined. Just couldn't figure out how to combine them together. I'll test this out, thanks.

Comment: If it works for you, please don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Comment: It hasn't worked yet, or I would have. Might just be a transcription error on my part, but it keeps returning the list null. Did you test it out?

Comment: Of course! The last lines in my answer were generated by the program. Please copy-paste the whole thing in a separate window and try again, maybe there's something different with respect to your code.

Comment: I tested the code in Racket - although I'm not using non-standard procedures and it should work on any Scheme interpreter.